# Percentuage on Na Values (Dataframe and Variables) on R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate percentage of `NA`-values in a dataframe and for variables.

My dataframe has this:

```
mean(is.na(dataframe))
# 0.03354
```

How I read this result? Na 0,033%?  I don't understand.

For the individual variables I did the following for the count of `NA`s

```
sapply(DATAFRAME, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

Then, for the percentage of `NA`-values:

```
colMeans(is.na(VARIABLEX))
```

Doesn't work because I get the following error:

> "x must be an array of at least two dimension"

Why does this error occur? Anyway, afterwards I tried the following:

```
mean(is.na(VariableX))
# 0.1188
```

Should I interpret this as having 0.11% `NA`-values?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  
Please read [ask] and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and [mcve] ... then edit your question!

Comment: How can we store the percentages of missings by column in a new data frame?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just divide the number of rows containing NAs by the total number of rows:

```
df <- data.frame(data = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 4, NA, 7, NA))

percent_NA <- NROW(df[is.na(df$data),])/NROW(df)
```

Which gives:

```
> percent_NA
[1] 0.6666667
```

Which means there are 66,67% NAs in my dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue you are trying to solve. It all works as expected.
First, a dataset since you haven't provided one.

```
set.seed(6180)  # make it reproducible
dat <- data.frame(x = sample(c(1:4, NA), 100, TRUE),
                  y = sample(c(1:5, NA), 100, TRUE))
```

Now the code for sums.

```
s <- sapply(dat, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
s
# x  y 
#18 13
sum(s)
#[1] 31
sum(is.na(dat))
#[1] 31

colSums(is.na(dat))
# x  y 
#18 13
```

The same goes for means, be it `mean` or `colMeans`.
**EDIT.**
Here is the code to get the means of `NA` values per column/variable and a grand total.

```
sapply(dat, function(x) mean(is.na(x)))
#   x    y 
#0.18 0.13
colMeans(is.na(dat))   # Same result, faster
#   x    y 
#0.18 0.13
mean(is.na(dat))       # overall mean
#[1] 0.155
```

Comment: I would percentage Na Values dataframe and variables. I have dataframe
[1] 44750     7. For % of 7 variables I did -> percentvar <- nrow(df [is.na(df$variable),])/NROW(df) - for each variable. For % on dataframe I did  ->sum(is.na(df))/prod(dim(df)) -. Is it correctly for you?

Comment: @jessicascucchia OK, I will edit my question. There are simple ways of doing what you want. Note that in the code above you really don't need `sapply`, `colSums` and `colMeans` do it for you and are more efficient.

Comment: @jessicascucchia And yes, `sum(is.na(df))/prod(dim(df))` does give the same result as my last line of code. But mine is simpler. **Note:** don't name your data frame `df` since it already is a `base R` function.